# can lawyers/senate public commitee meetings ask questions which might be covered by NDA's

Tags: contract-law, constitutional-law, corporate-law, us-senate

I'm just taking the recent Mark Zuckerberg Senate hearings which were held in the open in the United States. Is there some sort of fine line that the Senate has to follow? Can they ask any questions even if it may impinge upon any non-disclosure agreements signed by the defendant, e.g. regarding trade secrets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Senators, and anyone else for that matter, can ask any questions they want.

The witness is required to answer the questions only if under subpoena, and only if the answer of the question would neither require disclosure of privileged information nor violate a 5th Amendment right (which is a form of privilege).

Many things that are the subject of an NDA are not privileged information, and the fact that someone claims that something is a trade secret does not automatically make it privileged information.

Privileges can be established by statute, court rule or at common law.

Comment: Could you perhaps illustrate with an example of an employee of a producer of food products who is asked a question that would require the disclosure of a secret ingredient, contrary to an NDA between employee and employer?  Does the employee risk being caught in a choice between being found in contempt and being sued for breaching the NDA?

Comment: @phoog That is a legitimate thing to ask, but a hard thing to answer both in a procedural sense and in a substantive law sense. If someone else wants to take that on, more power to them, but I'm not going to take that more specific question on just now.

Comment: I may be misreading your second paragraph, did you mean that the witness is only required to answer under subpeona, but under subpeona are only allowed to refuse to answer if the question would require dislcouse of privileged information or violate a 5th Amendment right?

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Yes. You have restated it correctly.

Comment: You've missed a *"not"* there, then. *"... only if the answer of the question would **not** require disclosure of privileged information ..."*.

Comment: I think the answer is right, but the implications are a bit surprising! I suspect that in @phoog’s example, the answerer would not be in breach of the NDA because to the extent that it prevented compliance with a lawful subpoena, it would be void for illegality. I hope someone will do the research and find a good example of this coming up in practice.

Comment: @sjy The answerer would have not liability for breach of the NDA in the circumstances described. The analysis is much simpler for testimony in court where there are court rules and lots of precedents and a comparatively simple process involved. Senate subpoenas are enforced in a federal trial court in DC rather than directly by the Senate which makes it all much more complex procedurally, and rules & precedents related to disclosures of trade secrets and similar information in court aren't directly applicable to Senate proceedings, which is why it is much more complicated for Senate testimony.